# How do you get the text value of an h1 by clicking an html button?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I set a javascript variable to the text value in a specific h1 by clicking a button?

Comment: Where are your codes and what you have tried so far ?

Comment: This should be closed as offtopic

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. Question is far too broad and you are expected to try to solve problems like this yourself....and ask when you have code that doesn't work as expected

Comment: @charlietfl sorry dude, could you at least point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are giving the `h1` an id and then calling it in the javascript (For my example I gave it an id by the name of `textTest`).

HTML:

```
<h1 id="textTest">Hello there!</h1>
<button onclick="getElementText("textTest")">This will get the text of the <h1>!</button>
```

JS:

```
function getElementText(elementID){
   var elementText = document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML;
   console.log(elementText); //Will print out "Hello there!"
}
```